# How to send data from different controllers/actions to the same view?

Tags: laravel, routes, controllers

This is my first experience with Laravel, and so far I'm having some difficulties passing data to views. My app is a single page website with one menu on the top listing all the product categories and below there is a grid of thumbnails for each item or product. Visitors are able to filter the products by their category of choice.

```
Route::get('home/{category}', array('as'=>'itemshome', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@index'));
```

So in my ItemsControllers I fetch some items from the item model and pass them to the view.

```
class ItemsController extends \BaseController {


public function index($category)
{
    return View::make('home/index', ['items' => Item::where('publishtime', '<', 
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->where('category_id','=',$category)->paginate(24)]);

}
```

At this point I'm not sure if I should send data from the Category model to the home view using the ItemsController, or if it would it be a better approach to define a new CategoryController and pass the values from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use another controller to send data to the same view during the same request.

Either add it to the view make call:

```
return View::make('home/index', [
    'items' => Item::where('publishtime', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->where('category_id','=',$category)->paginate(24),
    'categories' => Category::all()
];
```

Or, if the category data actually has nothing to do with the items controller but is needed by the view, you could register a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)

```
View::composer('home/index', function($view){
    $view->with('categories', Category::all());
});
```

Now every time when the `home/index` view gets rendered, `categories` will be injected.

You can actually place the view composer anywhere you want. However I recommend you add a new file `app/composers.php` to store all your view composers. Then you need to include it somewhere. For example in `app/start/global.php` at the bottom:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Comment: First suggestion is working thanks!, just wonder where I have to put the view composer code.

Comment: I updated the answer with details on where to put the view composer